# ExtJs 6.0.0.640 - Ext.view.View - multiSelect config not working

Tags: javascript, extjs

I have made up [this little Sencha Fiddle example](https://fiddle.sencha.com/#fiddle/12nu).

As you can see `multiSelect` is set to `true`.

But if i press `Ctrl + left mouse click` i **cant select multiple** pictures.

**Why doesn't the config work?**

---

I have also tried setting:

`my_view.getSelectionModel().mode = 'MULTI';`

since `multiSelect` is marked as `DEPRECATED`.

But this didn't work either.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the `selectionModel` config, like:

```
selectionModel: {
    mode: 'MULTI'
}
```

Working example: https://fiddle.sencha.com/#fiddle/12o0

Comment: This is so weird: I copy&paste your complete sencha-fiddle code into my sencha-fiddle and the multiselect is not working. But your sencha-fiddle works. You know what might be causing this?

Comment: have you copied the `css` too?